# gradle 3.5 do not recognize class from terminal

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I'm using Intillij with gradle 3.5 and I want to call specific class in project. in me build.gradle I have

```
ext.testFile = System.getProperty('Test_Plan') ?: 'testng.xml'
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
        useTestNG {
            suites "src/main/resources/${testFile}"
        }
}
```

that use to call suite in my project, but I'll want to ignore the 'test' and just call from terminal

> gradle test --tests TC1001 or gradle test -Dtest.single=TC1001

and this 2 options give the error

```
 * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
 No tests found for given includes: [com.automation.navigateSuite.TC1001]
```

the directory hierarchy is

> src/test/java/com.automation/navigateSuite/TC1001.java

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you really have a directory named `com.automation`? If so, you shouldn't. Instead, you should have a directory com, containing a directory automation.

Comment: @jb-nizet I change the directory name and it didn't change the error

Comment: acutely  com.automation is a package  maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: The hierarchie should be `src/test/java/com/automation/navigateSuite/TC1001.java` Dot should never be used in a package name.

Comment: after a while i try to do gradle test --tests *TC1001 and the test work , I understand that this way the gradle search without the hierarchy issue